# pdfJsLib - how to enableXfa

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

I'm using the mozilla pdfJsLib module to render a .pdf-file.

I have to [enableXfa](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/api/draft/module-pdfjsLib.html) which default state is `false`

I tried the following syntax:

```js
pdfjslib
.getDocument({url, enableXfa: true})
.promise.then(...
```

---

but my pdf-file with form elements are empty. I expected the pdf form fields to be filled.

Is my declaration of `.getDocument({url, enableXfa: true})` right?